# Traversal and Access via id implementation hash_map & vector

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap

I am designing the core of my program and have various entities which I currently loop through to call `update()`. I have around ten `vector`s containing my objects, although this might grow to a much larger amount in future. I have just realized I will need to look these up via an `id` fairly regularly, so I am forced to loop through all elements to look for the correct id.

I am thinking of creating a `hashmap` that contains the `id` along with a pointer to the object itself. Is this the most efficient way to do this? The id's are semi random although they only increase throughout program, with each element in each of the lists having an unique id (each time one is assigned the id counter goes up). The elements in vectors now get removed and added often. I haven't worked much with hashmaps, other than a small bit in java, so I am unsure if this will be an efficient route to go. I believe the code will still be readable, but are there any options other than hash_map that would be better suited for this? Thanks

Comment: That will have O(1) lookup time, but will not be as memory efficient as just keeping your vectors sorted by id and using a binary search. You may want to take a look at [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/container/)'s `flat_map<>` if memory overhead is a concern.

Comment: `The elements in vectors now get removed and added often` -- this probably means that keeping these objects in vectors is not ideal, unless you always remove from the very end of the vector.

Comment: @SevaTitov It is impossible for me to determine how long they can last, there is a lot of throughput coming in and out. Some of the early ones could last for hours, some of the early ones might last all but a few seconds. It think it is unfeasible to have a large vector and iterate over all empty elements in attempts to reduce this, since iteration happens anywhere from 10->100 times a second generally. I am not positive of the effects(always learning) though so you may be onto something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have 10 `vector`s - if the objects can be stored in one sorted `vector`, you may use `binary_search` to find the object (remember to sort it after every insert).

Of course, the `hash_map` also works, at the cost of space/memory.

Comment: @ildjams recommendation, `flat_map`, seems quite appropriate too. They are ordered-vector based associative containers - however, if you have `vector`s already, you may maintain the ones you have yourself.

Comment: The reason for being is each holds a different type of object, yet they all use the same id system. I suppose I could create something that would just hold each object and then refer to that. But right now I can have situations with a few hundred inserts and deletions per second, with a few thousand objects, also, the insertions sometimes happen each loop and sometimes won't for a few seconds- that is out of my control. With thousands of elements I don't think it's feasible to sort.